# Consuming a secured Web Service

Tags: c#

I'm new in consuming web services and i have to access a state-run web service.
I was given an app.config file, a certificate file (.cer) and some general instructions.

Haven'n used Visual Studio 2008 Express before but i have 15 years experience in writing vb5/6 code.

Anyway, I installed the .cer file using mmc and then opened a new project and
I added the System.Runtime.Serialization and System.ServiceModel
I addedd a service reference to the WSDL link
I included app.config file in my project
and wrote the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EchoSvcClientConsAppl
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        ConAp66.myserviceref.ServiceClient clientProxy = new ConAp66.myserviceref.ServiceClient();

        clientProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xx";
        clientProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xx";

        clientProxy.Open();

        if (clientProxy != null)
            System.Console.WriteLine("init succeeded ");
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine("init error");

        String ar1 = "xxx";
        String ar2 = "xxx";
        String ar3 = "xxx";
        ConAp66.myserviceref.eRes r = clientProxy.getRes1(ar1, ar2, ar3);

        if (r.status != null)
             System.Console.WriteLine("ok");
        else
             System.Console.WriteLine(r.error);

        clientProxy.Close();

        System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
      }
  }
```

---

i get an error on line:
ConAp66.myserviceref.eRes r = clientProxy.getRes1(ar1, ar2, ar3);

saying that i have token authentication problems

any clues???
Your help would be greatly appreciated since i really don't know what to do...

Update:

I added trace to app.config and got:

Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message.
This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there
is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.
This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is
not using security.

after some googling i found out that is should put
enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
in my app.config

I did that, but nothing happened

Comment: Is the web services on https? If so you'll need to install a certificate and possibly code to allow permissive connections for testing.

Comment: Not related, but the `if (clientProxy != null)` block is unnecessary - if it's null, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` before you get there, and you can guarantee that it's not null because you're `new`ing it up.

Comment: Please post your config and the full error message.

Comment: The web service is on https and i have installed the .cer file i was given. Full error is InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException Message="FailedAuthentication : The security token cannot be authenticated." What config should i post?

Comment: I edited the title because your problem almost certainly has nothing to do with which IDE you're using.

Comment: Thanks John Saunders. However my problem is still here... :(

Comment: @user2686958:  Post the app.config for your application.

Comment: thanks @zimdanen, here's the link to [app.config](http://www.ambyx.net/app.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to accept the certificate server as follow.

```
public static bool CertHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
     // Says that you accept the certificate.
     // In production environment you have to really check if you  can accept the certificate.  
     return true;
}

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertHandler;
```

Add these lines before the proxy creation.

Namespace of [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) class is System.Net.

Namespace of [X509Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate) class is System.Security.Cryptography.

Comment: i run the project and get that communication object System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel can not be used because it's faulted. the error is on the line ConAp66.myserviceref.eRes r = clientProxy.getRes1(ar1, ar2, ar3) like originally happens